# Ansible: Archive module for Windows

Tags: windows, ansible, zip

Is there a way to create a zip file on Windows with Ansible? I'm using the archive module, but it's not working

Comment: Please elaborate in more details than just "not working". Please show any error messages you get and what steps you already took.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible create a zip file backup on windows host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197468/ansible-create-a-zip-file-backup-on-windows-host)

Comment: Thanks Mxx for your answer. Yes, I just want to have an update for this link.  Do you know if the archive module works now for Windows host?